# Angular Spring Data Rest - Exchange the underlying fetch function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use angular-spring-data-rest and was following the documentation at:
http://guylabs.ch/project/angular-spring-data-rest/
Under section "Exchange the underlying fetch function" it provides following example to define a custom fetch function:

```
myApp.config(function (SpringDataRestAdapterProvider) {

    // set the new resource function
    SpringDataRestAdapterProvider.config({
        'fetchFunction': function (url, key, data, fetchLinkNames, recursive) {
            // fetch the url and add the key to the data object
        }
    });
});
```

How is it possible to define a function that will fetch a url within the config function? As angular.config only accepts Providers how am I supposed to get the $http or $resource or any other service in there? Documentation provides a similar example to replace the resource function as well. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to use the `$http` service inside the configuration phase. You need to use the Angular injector:

```
myApp.config(function (SpringDataRestAdapterProvider) {

    // set the new fetch function
    SpringDataRestAdapterProvider.config({
        fetchFunction: function (url, key, data, fetchLinkNames, recursive) {
            var $http = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$http');

            $http.get('/rest/endpoint').then(function (responseData) {
                console.log(responseData);
            })
        }
    });
});
```

I tested it within the https://github.com/guylabs/angular-spring-data-rest-sample project and I also updated the documentation: https://github.com/guylabs/angular-spring-data-rest#configuration-of-the-springdatarestadapter.

I hope this helps and thanks for mentioning it!

Thanks and regards,

Guy

Comment: I decided to unwrap embedded item arrays in my factories so I haven't tested this but I might try this in the future. Thanks.